# Calling one method from another in a Javascript class

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, methods, referenceerror

When defining a class in Javascript, how can I call one method from another one?

```
exports.myClass = function () {

    this.init = function() {
        myInternalMethod();
    }

    this.myInternalMethod = function() {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

The code above gives me the following error when executing it:

> ReferenceError: myInternalMethod is not defined

I also tried this.myInternalMethod and self.myInternalMethod, but both lead to errors.
What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Cache the value of `this` in a variable on the higher scope, then use that. `var self = this; self.method();`

Comment: Also, JavaScript has no classes. It is a prototype-based object-oriented language.

Comment: @elclanrs You must know that this is a very bad idea, unless you actually want to always refer to the last instanciated object. That said, the question is not full of explanations...

Comment: @ elclanrs: That solved my problem. Would you mind making an answer out of this?

Answer (score 6):

I have created this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VFKkC/ Here you can call myInternalMedod()

```
var myClass = function () {

    this.init = function() {
        this.myInternalMethod();
    }

    this.myInternalMethod = function() {
        console.log("internal");
    }
}

var c = new myClass();

c.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.myInternalMethod()` does seem to work, though:

```
var exports = {};
exports.myClass = function () {

    this.init = function() {
        this.myInternalMethod();
    }

    this.myInternalMethod = function() {
        //Do something
    }
}

var x = new exports.myClass();
x.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a private member?

```
exports.myClass = function () {

    this.init = function() {
        myInternalMethod();
    }

    function myInternalMethod() {
        //Do something
    }
}
```